# How to write JPQL SELECT with embedded id?

Tags: java, jpa, jpql, composite-key

I'm using Toplink essentials (JPA) + GlassFish v3 + NetBean 6.9

I have one table with composite primary key:

```
table (machine)
----------------
|PK machineId  |
|PK workId     |
|              |
|______________|
```

I created 2 entity classes one for entity itself and second is PK class.

```
public class Machine {
   @EmbeddedId
   protected MachinePK machinePK;

   //getter setters of fields..
}

public class MachinePK {
    @Column(name = "machineId")
    private String machineId;

    @Column(name = "workId")
    private String workId;

}
```

Now.. **how do I write SELECT clause with JPQL with WHERE???**

This fails.

```
SELECT m FROM Machine m WHERE m.machineId = 10
```

http://www.mail-archive.com/users@openjpa.apache.org/msg03073.html

According to the web page, add "val"? No it fails too.

```
   SELECT m FROM Machine m WHERE m.machineId.val = 10
```

In both case, the error is:

```
    Exception Description: Error compiling the query 
[SELECT m FROM Machine m WHERE m.machineId.val = 10], 
line 1, column 30: unknown state or association field 
[MachineId] of class [entity.Machine].
```

Answer (score 96, accepted):

```
SELECT m FROM Machine m WHERE m.machinePK.machineId = 10
```

Comment: How to convert that to JPA Criteria?

Comment: SELECT m FROM Machine m WHERE m.machinePK.machineId = :criteria

Comment: if using HQL could you also do SELECT m FROM Machine m WHERE m.machinePK in (:listOfKeys) ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30095676/composite-key-query-using-hql-and-separate-idclass

Comment: i have a situation where the fields in the embeddable class is also other user defined classes and i have to evaluate a field in that user defined class. any idea how to do that? @Query("SELECT e from ElectionContestant e where e.primaryKey.contestant.contestId=?#{0} AND e.primaryKey.election.elecId=?#{1}")

Answer (score 6):

**Tested with Hibernate 4.1 and JPA 2.0**

Make the following changes in order to work:

Class *Machine.java*

```
public class Machine {
   @EmbeddedId
   protected MachinePK machinePK;

   //getter & setters...
}
```

Class *MachinePK.java*

```
@Embeddable
public class MachinePK {
    @Column(name = "machineId")
    private String machineId;

    @Column(name = "workId")
    private String workId;

    //getter & setters...
}
```

...and for the JPQL query pass all column names:

```
Query query = em.createQuery("SELECT c.machinePK.machineId, c.machinePK.workId, "
                + "FROM Machine c WHERE c.machinePK.machineId=?");
query.setParameter(1, "10");

Collection results = query.getResultList();

Object[] obj = null;
List<MachinePK> objPKList = new ArrayList<MachinePK>();
MachinePK objPK = null;
Iterator it = results.iterator();
while(it.hasNext()){
    obj = (Object[]) it.next();
    objPK = new MachinePK();
    objPK.setMachineId((String)obj[0]);
    objPK.setWorkId((String)obj[1]);
    objPKList.add(objPK);
    System.out.println(objPK.getMachineId());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use annotation [@Query](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/jpa/repository/Query.html), you can use element [nativeQuery](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/jpa/repository/Query.html#nativeQuery--) = true.