# Using @EmbeddedId with JpaRepository

Tags: java, spring, jpa, jpql, spring-data

I have simple Entitly class with the `@EmbeddedId` (`Integer` and `String` fields in separate class). And I use the Spring Data (`org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository`) to access the database (MySql), with the normal Id the queries are working fine, both the generated by Spring and the ones wrote by myself. With the `EmbeddedId` I didnt manage to create the correct query. What I want to do is to select all the id (one of the fields of embeddedId for which some condition occurs) Here you have some code samples, maybe somebody will have an idea how to solve it.
The entity class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="table_name")
public class EntityClass {

    @EmbeddedId
    private EmbeddedIdClass id;
    private String  someField;
    //rest of implemetation
}
```

the EmbeddedId class:

```
@Embeddable
public class EmbeddedIdClass implements Serializable {

public EmbeddedIdClass(Long id, String language) {
    super();
    this.id = id;
    this.language = language;
}

public UserAdTextId() {}        

@Column(name="ad_id", nullable=false)
    private Integer id;

    @Column(name="language_code", nullable=false)
    private String  language;
    //rest of implemetation
}
```

and the repository:

```
@Transactional(readOnly=true)
public interface MyRepository extends JpaRepository<EntityClass, EmbeddedIdClass> {
    @Query("select distinct ad_id from EntityClass where userId = :userId and (/*here the conditions*/)")
    public Page<Integer> findUserAdsWithSearchString(@Param("userId") Integer userId, @Param("searchString") String searchString, Pageable page);
//rest of implemetation
}
```

I didn't find any documentation how to create the methods for supporting the @EmbeddedId, I was trying many different method names, but I always get exceptions from the method parser..

Answer (score 19, accepted):

It seems your query is using column names. It should contain the property names, including navigation into embedded objects. There's also a related question here on SO: [How to write JPQL SELECT with embedded id?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4676904/851811)

```
select distinct id.id from EntityClass where userId = :userId and (...)
```

The first `id` refers to attribute `id` of `EntityClass` (of type `EmbeddedIdClass`), and the second one refers to the `id` property of `EmbeddedIdClass`.

Also, make sure there's a `userId` property in `EntityClass`.

Comment: It's right, i have to use the field names and browse through them, however I get the output sql with seelct count(distinct...) Where is the count from?? the return type is Page<Long> or List<Long> (I was trying both...

Comment: The answer is ok, another problem I had was a pageable... it seems that the queries with distinct or group by cant handle Pageable... pity:(

Answer (score 49):

(by Yosi Lev)
This can be done as the following:
Suppose your main entity is:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="JRULES_FLOW")
public class JrulesFlow implements Serializable {
   private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

   @EmbeddedId
   private JrulesFlowPK id;

   @Column(name="NEXT_SEQ")
   private int nextSeq;

   @Column(name="REF_ID")
   private String refId;

   @Column(name="TASK_TYPE")
   private String taskType;

   @Column(name="VALUE_TO_FIND")
   private String valueToFind;
}
```

And your PK class is :

```
@Embeddable
public class JrulesFlowPK implements Serializable {
   //default serial version id, required for serializable classes.
   private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

   @Column(name="FLOW_ID")
   private String flowId;

   @Column(name="TASK_SEQ")
   private long taskSeq;
 }
```

The JPA repository method name shouls include the name of the id field in
the main class followed by the property you want to query uppon within the PK class:

```
public interface JrulesFlowRepository extends JpaRepository<JrulesFlow, 
      JrulesFlowPK> { // NOTE: put here both classes - also the pk class..
   public List<JrulesFlow>  findByIdFlowId(String flowId);  // Id - is the 
                  // @EmbeddedId in JrulesFlow. FlowId is an attribute 
                  // within JrulesFlowPK
}
```

Comment: for multiple columns-- findByIdCol1AndIdCol2AndIdCol3(String col1, String col2, String col3);  works