# SELECT query with composite primary key

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, jpa

In a spring mvc app using hibernate and jpa, I recently switched to a composite primary key using an `@Embeddable` class.  As a result, I need to update the JPA query that returns a given object based on its unique id.  The following is the JPA code that used to work, but which no longer returns a result:

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public Concept findConceptById(BigInteger id) {
    Query query = this.em.createQuery("SELECT conc FROM Concept conc WHERE conc.id =:cid");
    query.setParameter("cid", id);
    return (Concept) query.getSingleResult();
}
```

**How do I change the above query so that it returns the Concept with the most recent `effectiveTime` for the given `id`?**  Note that `id` and `effectiveTime` are the two properties of the `ConceptPK`  composite primary key, and that thus the property definitions and getters and setters for `id` and `effectiveTime` are in the `ConceptPK` class and NOT in the `Concept` class.

The error thrown by the above is:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException:  
Parameter value [786787679] did not match expected type [myapp.ConceptPK]
```

This is how the primary key is now defined in the `Concept` class:

```
private ConceptPK conceptPK;
```

And here is the code for the `ConceptPK` class:

```
@Embeddable
class ConceptPK implements Serializable {

    @Column(name="id", nullable=false)
    protected BigInteger id;

    @Column(name="effectiveTime", nullable=false)
    @Type(type="org.jadira.usertype.dateandtime.joda.PersistentDateTime")
    private DateTime effectiveTime;

    public ConceptPK() {}
    public ConceptPK(BigInteger bint, DateTime dt) {
        this.id = bint;
        this.effectiveTime = dt;
    }

    /** getters and setters **/
    public DateTime getEffectiveTime(){return effectiveTime;}
    public void setEffectiveTime(DateTime ad){effectiveTime=ad;}

    public void setId(BigInteger id) {this.id = id;}
    public BigInteger getId() {return id;}

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) { 
        if (this == obj) return true;
        if (obj == null) return false;
        if (getClass() != obj.getClass()) return false;
        final ConceptPK other = (ConceptPK) obj;
        if (effectiveTime == null) {
            if (other.effectiveTime != null) return false;
            } else if (!effectiveTime.equals(other.effectiveTime)) return false;
        if (id == null) {
            if (other.id != null) return false;
        } else if (!id.equals(other.id)) return false;
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() { 
        int hash = 3;
        hash = 53 * hash + ((effectiveTime == null) ? 0 : effectiveTime.hashCode());
        hash = 53 * hash + ((id == null) ? 0 : id.hashCode());
        return hash;
    }
}
```

Comment: I think you should consider query `SELECT conc FROM Concept conc WHERE conc.id.id =:cid order by conc.id.effectiveTime desc` and get its `uniqueResult()`.

Comment: @AlexeyMalev Thank you.  Do you see that I would need to create a `conceptPK`? And that `effectiveTime` is not nullable in the code above?  So I don't see how I can get the most recent `effectiveTime` without making some changes.  In the query function above, `id` is a biginteger and not the primary key.

Comment: Why would you need to create a `conceptPK`? Where? Its fields is not nullable, yes, but I do not see how this relates to the question and my previous comment. Regarding `Concept` class - I assumed it has `ConceptPK` in the field named `id`. If it's not - just rename the `id` between two dots in my query above.

Comment: @AlexeyMalev I tried your code and got the following new error: `Caused by: org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: Concept is not mapped [SELECT conc FROM Concept conc WHERE conc.conceptPK.id =:cid order by conc.conceptPK.effectiveTime desc]`. What do you suggest?

Comment: First - remove `order by` clause and check whether the error is still here. Second - put a `Concept` class also here, I think taking a look at its mapping may help resolving your problem. Third - do not be such agressive.

Comment: @AlexeyMalev I did not intend to sound aggressive.  Sorry.  I did remove the `order by` clause but got the same error.  I uploaded `Concept` to a file sharing site.  What do you think?  Here is the link:  https://jumpshare.com/v/aYAM5sqo64M8Lb8DZfiv?b=1PQWFj47uEeL0Tqvpx5o

Comment: Well.. it seems your entity name is not `Concept`. Try replacing `Concept` with `SnomedConcept` in the query in `from` clause.

Comment: @AlexeyMalev Yes, I know.  I already accounted for that.  I just removed Snomed for the posting.  I am sorry if that caused confusion, but that is not the problem.  What else do you see?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/52062/discussion-between-alexey-malev-and-codemed)

Comment: @AlexeyMalev your `conc.conceptPk.id` approach solved my problem.  If you post that as an answer, I will mark it as the accepted answer, because you said it before the other answerer said it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To use parts of composite primary key in JPA query, you have to address them using its variable names:

```
public Concept findConceptById(BigInteger id) {
    Query query = this.em.createQuery("SELECT conc FROM Concept conc WHERE conc.conceptPK.id =:cid order by conc.conceptPK.effectiveTime desc");
    query.setParameter("cid", id);
    return (Concept) query.getSingleResult();
}
```

I used `Concept` as entity name assuming the class with `@Entity` annotation is also named `Concept`.

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4676904/how-to-write-jpql-select-with-embedded-id) contains information about similar problem, you may find it useful.

Comment: I put up a bounty on another hibernate question.  Are you willing to help me with it?  here is the link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25454703/constraint-violation-when-persisting-one-to-many-relation

Answer (score 4):

Please try this

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public Concept findConceptById(BigInteger id) {
    Query query = this.em.createQuery("from Concept conc WHERE conc.conceptPK.id = :cid order by conc.conceptPK.effectiveTime desc");
    query.setParameter("cid", id);
    return (Concept) query.getSingleResult();
}
```

Make sure conceptPK has getter and setter methods in Concept class.